# Search and replace patterns on multiple line

Tags: regex, sed

I have a pattern like

```
Fixed pattern
text which can change(world)
```

I want to replace this with

```
Fixed pattern
text which can change(hello world)
```

What I am trying to use

```
cat myfile | sed -e "s#\(Fixed Pattern$A_Z_a_z*\(\)#\1 hello#g > newfile
```

UPDATE:
The above word world is also a variable and will change
Basically add hello after the first parenthesis encountered after the expression.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the goal to add `'hello '` inside of every opening parentheses on the line after `'Fixed pattern'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your goal is to add `'hello '` inside of every opening parentheses on the line after `'Fixed pattern'`, here is a solution that should work:

```
sed -e '/^Fixed pattern$/!b' -e 'n' -e 's/(/(hello /' myfile
```

Here is an explanation of each portion:

```
/^Fixed pattern$/!b    # skip all of the following commands if 'Fixed pattern'
                       #   doesn't match
n                      # if 'Fixed pattern' did match, read the next line
s/(/(hello /           # replace '(' with '(hello '
```

Comment: @PravinCG - No problem, I just edited it to remove the `g` after the replacement, since your edit indicates you only want to perform the replacement on the first `(`.

Answer (score 2):

To do this with sed, use `n`:

```
sed '/Fixed pattern/{n; s/world/hello world/}' myfile
```

You may need to be more careful, but this should work for most situations.  Whenever sed sees the `Fixed pattern` (you may want to use line anchors `^` and `$`), it will read the next line and then apply the substitution to it.

Comment: Updated the question, world is also a variable